# Yii2 : Invalid Parameter in query : ' >'

Tags: yii2, query-builder, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying the following query in `Yii2`

```
Course::find()->where(['course_id'=>$course_ids])->andWhere(['>', 'id', $sample_id])->asArray()->all()
```

and this returns the error `Found unknown operator in query : >` .
Not able to figure out the mistake.

Database used : mySQL

Comment: What kind if database you are using?

Comment: @AliMasudianPour mysql

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5456#issuecomment-58531535

Answer (score 0):

vishnu I think this kind of operation are not allowed by yii2. And the proper way of writing this query in yii2 is.

```
Course::find()->where(['course_id'=>$course_ids])->andWhere('id > :id',[':id' =>$sample_id])->asArray()->all();
```

try with this query and you can achive what you expect. and there is good discussion on this link https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2315 checkout this too.

Comment: https://github.com/suryaharshan1/invoker-api - link to the repo.. please check the action setcourselist in User controller under api/versions/v1/controllers

Comment: Te version I was using is 2.0.0 , I applied the fixes as in https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/commit/1c4d24a51c33a31b41028c1ca0f30a9bc30d3c75. Now its working. Thank u.

Comment: if you got it working please accept the answer and upvote it. @Vishnu

Answer (score 0):

Yii versions 2.0.0(which can be found from composer.lock) don't support the relational operators. The bug has been fixed in yii version 2.0.6. The query worked after updating to 2.0.6